# How do I cite an equation that has a typo in the source?

Tags: citations, mathematics, citation-style

I want to cite an equation in my thesis that has a minor typo in the cited source (the wrong letter is used for an index). How should I do that? Can I simply correct the typo in my paper without commenting on it, or should I indicate somehow that the equation has been altered? I’m supposed to use APA style.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should indicate what the typo was and that you corrected it. This will prevent your readers getting confused if/when they look up the reference, and related annoyances (e.g., the referee accusing you of making an error, your professor giving you a bad grade, or people generally just thinking you are sloppy). Noting the correction will also create a historical record of the typo, which could be useful for other researchers working on the same topic in the future.

Related discussion for a non-mathematical correction: [Quoting a typo: Do I really have to do "sic", or can I just fix the sentence?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/94282/40589)

Comment: Could be a case where a footnote does the job. Cite as usual and explain the correction in the footnote.

Comment: @Snijderfrey, footnotes are fine in general, but not permitted with every "style".

Comment: Sure, a footnote is an appropriate way to mention it. I think I did exactly that in a recent paper of mine.

Comment: How do you use foot notes in an equation? A ¹ or ² can easily be confused with an exponent.

Comment: @Michael I assume that there will be some text introducing the equation, and you can place the footnote there.

Comment: @Michael as Snijderfrey says, the footnote is attached to the surrounding text rather than placing the marker in the equation itself.

Comment: @Michael There's an [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1184/) for that.

Comment: @Michael symbol footnotes *, †, etc., or alphabetical would help, though clearly not in all cases.  Quite a lot of Physics journals use numeric superscript citations and with a little care that's not a problem